# XAML options quality in a video

Tags: c#, xaml, youtube

Is there anyway to create a option that the user can choose a quality in the moment he/she watching the video? Like YouTube and is there anyway to create a option the user can watch in full screen too.

This is the code behind  in this moment i put the video in low quality but if the user want to see in high quality then I need to show a option in the application to up the quality like I before say YouTube.

```
 var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("2rJwYN_SmOU", YouTubeQuality.QualityLow);
```

This is the xaml code.

```
<Grid x:Name="grdVideo" Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
   <MediaElement  x:Name="meTestVideo"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="578"  Margin="188,128,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1000"/>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course.
Rather than passing in the fixed `YouTubeQuality.QualityLow` value you'll want to pass in a value of the appropriate type, and have UI that allows the user to select which value of that type they want to use.
For example, create some new properties on your form:

```
public List<YouTubeQuality> QualityChoices = new List<YouTubeQuality>;
private YouTubeQuality selectedQuality;
```

Populate the QualityChoices list:

```
public MainPage()
    {

        this.InitializeComponent();

        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.Quality.Low);
        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.Quality.Medium);
        QualityChoices.Add(YouTubeQuality.Quality.High);

        PlayVideo(); 

    }
```

Then, say, put a combobox in your UI where you bind the `ItemSource` to the `QualityChoices`, and the `SelectedItem` to your `selectedQuality`, and then change your call to load the video so that you use the `selectedQuality` rather than the fixed value.

```
var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync("2rJwYN_SmOU", selectedQuality);
```

Note: I am guessing at the values for the YouTubeQuality class as it is not something I am familiar with. The documentation for that will let you know what are valid values.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but how can I populate that list?

Comment: See my edit. You can do it a number of ways, but I've stuck the adding of items to the `QualityChoices` list in your MainPage constructor (as seen on one of your other questions).

Comment: But you'll need to change how that MainPage constructor works anyway, if you're allowing the user to change the quality settings then you'll need to make changes to explicitly play the video rather than just triggering it to run in your constructor.

Comment: Yes I'll ready did it, ok and the combo box all to do is something like this <ComBox>Low</ComBox>?? I think is incorrect the combo box.

Comment: <ComboBox>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="LW">Low</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="MD">Medium</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Tag="HG">Hihg</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>

Comment: `this.myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.ItemsSource=QualityChoices;`

Comment: `<ComboBox x:Name="myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml" />`

Comment: Like this? private void myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
       
            this.myComboBoxThatICreatedInXaml.ItemsSource = QualityChoices;
        }

Comment: No, set the `ItemsSource` around about the same time that you define the `QualityChoices` list ... so in your constructor, say. In your `SelectionChanged` is when you can set your `selectedQuality` property.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand what you trying to say me.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't write your code for you. If you don't know what a constructor or the SelectionChanged event is, or what the ItemsSource of a ComboBox is, then you need to do some more basic self-learning. All the answers are in this comment thread, you just need to put them together into full code!

Comment: Yes i did it. Thank you a lot and is work. Sorry for the late response.